# Can't add more than one field user_meta_data supabase

Tags: supabase

I am doing a user registration through `nodejs`, this was already done in react but only with one field. The problem is that I try to send more than one field in the metadata of the record but it only adds `username` to the profiles table and not the others. However I get user information on the front end and there is the additional metadata that was added.

I'm using `supabase v2.0`

```
const createStripeAccount = async(req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: 'express',
      country: 'US',
      email: email,
      capabilities: {
        card_payments: {requested: true},
        transfers: {requested: true},
      }
    });
    const { id:stripeAccountId } = account;
   
    let newData = null;
    if(stripeAccountId) {
      console.log(typeof stripeAccountId)
      newData = await supabase.auth.signUp(
        {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          options: {
            data: {
              username: username,
              stripe_account_user_id: 'stripeAccountId', <---additional
              is_founder: true, <---additional
              website: 'www.sdsoso.cl' <---additional
            }
          }
        }
      )
    }
    const { data: {user} } = newData;
    console.log(newData)
    return res.json({
      user
    });
    
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
}
```

The response from the server is the full metadata sended. But in the table only add username and not the others.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using triggers to populate the table of the screenshot? Could you paste the definition of the trigger as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution and it was that I had forgotten that when I add new metadata I must update the function that is fired in the `supabase` trigger after registering.
So every time you want to pass more data to the profiles table after registration, update the function that is triggered. In my case:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO public.profiles(id, username, new_col_name)
  VALUES (
    NEW.id,
    NEW.raw_user_meta_data -> 'username',
    NEW.raw_user_meta_data -> 'new_col_name'
  );
  RETURN NEW;
END;
```